# How to use OAuth 2 without a client id?

Tags: authentication, security, oauth-2.0, oauth

I'm building a plugin for a 3rd party codebase (wordpress) to interface with my service and API. I'd like to use an OAuth 2 flow to let the user connect their wordpress plugin install to their account on my service.

Is there an acceptable flow which doesn't require a pre-defined Client ID (for the plugin) which still allows the user to authorize the plugin to have access to their account on my service? All flows that i've seen require a Client ID first.

Or, should I create a general Client ID for "Official Wordpress Plugin" and hard code that into the plugin? Keeping in mind that a user may have multiple wordpress sites with the plugin installed.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like [dynamic client registration](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7591#section-3.1) might be the best fit here. It typically works in 3 stages, after which clients can be managed (eg revoked) independently:

- Caller authenticates and gets a credential to enable registration, eg an access token with a `dcr` scope
- Caller registers a new client and receives a client ID and other details
- From that point onwards the dynamically created client ID is used to get normal access tokens

It is a design pattern really, and can be used in dynamic business scenarios, as long as registration credentials are backed by some kind of trust. Eg in Open Banking this works when a central authority issues client certificates, deployed to clients as a prerequisite.